# Can't instal package xlsx for R version 3.3.2

Tags: r, xlsx

I am trying to install the package on T version 3.3.2, but received the following message:

> ‘xlsx’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2)

Is there any way to overturn this problem?

Comment: I have the same R version and I've just installed it without problems with `install.packages("xlsx")`. Can you share your `sessionInfo()`? Maybe restarting the session...

Comment: I still cannot install, same message: package ‘xlsx’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2) 

and it does not appear when I run: sessionInfo()
Which info would you like to be shared?

Comment: Which operating system are you on?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
install.packages('xlsx', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

Comment: I did and still the same, no possible to install

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install it in R version 3.2.3 without any problem.

Try installing after starting R in the vanilla mode:

```
$  R --vanilla
```

It is likely to work. If not post the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [solution](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/package-xlsx-is-not-available-for-R-version-3-2-3-td4717416.html)

```
> install.packages("xlsx", repos = "http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/")
also installing the dependencies ‘rJava’, ‘xlsxjars’

trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/src/contrib/rJava_0.9-11.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 675188 bytes (659 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 659 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/src/contrib/xlsxjars_0.6.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 9477071 bytes (9.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 9.0 MB

trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/src/contrib/xlsx_0.6.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 315441 bytes (308 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 308 KB
```

Env:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)
```

```
platform       x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu    
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.0                         
year           2015                        
month          04                          
day            16                          
svn rev        68180                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
nickname       Full of Ingredients
```